# Springboot not creating database tables

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

i created my entity in springboot

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Table(name="users") 
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
}
```

i setted the database configuration in application.properties (i'm using MySQL XAMPP Apache server)

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/mediatech?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
server.port=8082
```

when i run the application it creates the database but not the tables, how can i fix it and create the database schema tables ?

Comment: just add constructors with all params and another without any params

Comment: Can you also show the packages structure in the project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on the value of **spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto** should be `update`.

the difference between create and update:

- "create": Hibernate will create the database schema from scratch on
  every application startup.
- "update": Hibernate will attempt to update the database schema to
  match the entity model. It will add tables, columns, and constraints
  as needed, but it won't drop existing tables or columns. This is a
  safer option for development and is sometimes used in production.

Comment: switched it to update still not work

Comment: make sure the code is access the package where the model is stored, if it is not accessed we should add this annotation @EntityScan("package name for model")
before boot class [the class that has this annotation @SpringBootApplication]

Answer (score 0):

You can set show-sql property to true to get the SQL queries ran by hibernate in logs.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.show_sql=true
```

Also the table name 'user' can be problematic as this is a reserved word in SQL, try using backticks or specify another name by using `@Table(name="users")`

Also ensure that you have getter/setters in entity class.

Comment: it's spring.jpa.show-sql , tried it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Lombok dependency with Spring Boot3 you may face issues.

1. Try to use no args and all args constructors created manually.
2. Make sure that repository interface has the name of the User class and Long as datatype.

It should look like below:

```java
UserRepository extends CrudRepository<Users,Long>
```